# [Hive]I got "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" while I query the hive database

Tags: java, hive

I always get "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" while I query the hive base(both hive-0.11.0 and hive-0.12.0), but sometimes not. Here is the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Hive Runtime Error while closing operators: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.close(ExecReducer.java:313)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:232)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:539)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:421)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.RowContainer.first(RowContainer.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.RowContainer.first(RowContainer.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.genUniqueJoinObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.checkAndGenObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:758)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.JoinOperator.endGroup(JoinOperator.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.close(ExecReducer.java:298)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.RowContainer.first(RowContainer.java:220)
    ... 13 more
```

Could someone help me?

Update my code:

```
    Select distinct jabberUseragent.gameID,agentPlayInfo.gameLabel,jabberUseragent.userAgent,CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(triggerUsageStart.generateDate,' '),triggerUsageStart.timezone),CONCAT(' ',triggerUsageStart.generateTime)) as generateDate,(unix_timestamp(CONCAT(CONCAT(triggerUsageStop.generateDate,' '),triggerUsageStop.generateTime)) - unix_timestamp(CONCAT(CONCAT(triggerUsageStart.generateDate,' '),triggerUsageStart.generateTime))) from
    (Select gameSession,gameID,userAgent from(Select distinct regexp_extract(t.payload,'playRequestId:(.*), playRequest',1) as gameSession,regexp_extract(t.payload,'gameId:(.*), userAgent:',1) as gameID,regexp_extract(t.payload,', userAgent:(.*), agentLocation',1) as userAgent,payload from (select * from ${hiveconf:DATA_BASE} p where p.dt >= '${hiveconf:LOW_DATE}' and p.dt <= '${hiveconf:UPPER_DATE}')  t where CONCAT(t.generatedate,t.generatetime) >= CONCAT('${hiveconf:LOW_DATE}','${hiveconf:LOW_TIME}') and CONCAT(t.generatedate,t.generatetime) <= CONCAT('${hiveconf:UPPER_DATE}','${hiveconf:UPPER_TIME}'))jabberUseragent where jabberUseragent.gameSession!='' and jabberUseragent.userAgent!='') jabberUseragent
join
    (Select gameID,gameLabel from(Select distinct regexp_extract(t.payload,'gameId=(.*),gameLabel=.*,configFilePath',1) as gameID,regexp_extract(t.payload,'gameId=.*,gameLabel=(.*),configFilePath',1) as gameLabel,payload from (select * from ${hiveconf:DATA_BASE} p where p.dt >= '${hiveconf:LOW_DATE}' and p.dt <= '${hiveconf:UPPER_DATE}')  t where CONCAT(t.generatedate,t.generatetime) >= CONCAT('${hiveconf:LOW_DATE}','${hiveconf:LOW_TIME}') and CONCAT(t.generatedate,t.generatetime) <= CONCAT('${hiveconf:UPPER_DATE}','${hiveconf:UPPER_TIME}'))agentPlayInfo where agentPlayInfo.gameID!='' and agentPlayInfo.gameLabel!='') agentPlayInfo
join
    (Select gameSession,generateDate,generateTime,timezone,payload from(Select distinct regexp_extract(t.payload,'GAME_SESSION=.*((.{8})-(.{4})-(.{4})-(.{4})-(.{12}))\" USAGE=\"([\\w\\-\\(\\)\\.]*,){41}9.*\"',1) as gameSession,generateDate,generateTime,timezone,payload from (select * from ${hiveconf:DATA_BASE} p where p.dt >= '${hiveconf:LOW_DATE}' and p.dt <= '${hiveconf:UPPER_DATE}')  t where t.payload like '%[e] usage_record%' and CONCAT(t.generatedate,t.generatetime) <= CONCAT('${hiveconf:UPPER_DATE}','${hiveconf:UPPER_TIME}') and CONCAT(t.generatedate,t.generatetime) >= CONCAT('${hiveconf:LOW_DATE}','${hiveconf:LOW_TIME}'))triggerStart where triggerStart.gameSession!='')triggerUsageStart
join
    (Select gameSession,generateDate,generateTime,timezone,payload from(Select distinct regexp_extract(t.payload,'GAME_SESSION=.*((.{8})-(.{4})-(.{4})-(.{4})-(.{12}))\" USAGE=\"([\\w\\-\\(\\)\\.]*,){41}[1-5].*\"',1) as gameSession,generateDate,generateTime,timezone,payload from (select * from ${hiveconf:DATA_BASE} p where p.dt >= '${hiveconf:LOW_DATE}' and p.dt <= '${hiveconf:UPPER_DATE}')  t where t.payload like '%[e] usage_record%' and CONCAT(t.generatedate,t.generatetime) <= CONCAT('${hiveconf:UPPER_DATE}','${hiveconf:UPPER_TIME}') and CONCAT(t.generatedate,t.generatetime) >= CONCAT('${hiveconf:LOW_DATE}','${hiveconf:LOW_TIME}'))triggerStop where triggerStop.gameSession!='')triggerUsageStop
on (jabberUseragent.gameSession = triggerUsageStart.gameSession and triggerUsageStart.gameSession = triggerUsageStop.gameSession and jabberUseragent.gameID = agentPlayInfo.gameID) order by generateDate
```

Sorry, I can't share my samples.
By the way, I've also got this exception before I got "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException"

```
javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Error executing SQL query "select PARTITIONS.PART_ID from PARTITIONS  inner join TBLS on PARTITIONS.TBL_ID = TBLS.TBL_ID   inner join DBS on TBLS.DB_ID = DBS.DB_ID  where TBLS.TBL_NAME = ? and DBS.NAME = ? and PARTITIONS.PART_NAME in (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)".
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:451)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.executeWithArray(JDOQuery.java:321)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.getPartitionsViaSqlFilterInternal(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:181)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.getPartitionsViaSqlFilter(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:82)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPartitionsByNamesInternal(ObjectStore.java:1717)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPartitionsByNames(ObjectStore.java:1700)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)......

NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "partitions" does not exist
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1591)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1340)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:192)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:471)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:373)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:258)......
```

Comment: Can you (a) show your code and (b) give a sample of your data?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information provided, only this can be a sensible solution to your problem.

I have put the method definition for [reference](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop.hive/hive-exec/0.7.0-cdh3u0/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/exec/persistence/RowContainer.java#RowContainer.first%28%29). Please go through it to understand

If you run down the source code closely, there are two areas / possibilities where `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` can be thrown.

- *Accessing* the *array* values of input splits from *Configuration*
- *Reading* the `Row` from `currentReadBlock` array (this is mostly not the case for the exception since it's size is greater than 0)

Please check your *set of input files for job* because InputFormat#split() method returns an array of InputSplit type. Each `InputSplit` is then assigned to an individual `Mapper` for *processing*. Mostly, the exception occurs while accessing this `InputSplit[]` array.

Comment: But I don't know why I can't get the exception every time. Because I use the same query string to query the different partitions, it will be get the exception at some partitions... So I think the input resource is the same format.

Comment: ok, then the only option is to debug your code line by line to see what really happens

Comment: Error is in this select query - select PARTITIONS.PART_ID from PARTITIONS  inner join TBLS on PARTITIONS.TBL_ID = TBLS.TBL_ID   inner join DBS on TBLS.DB_ID = DBS.DB_ID  where TBLS.TBL_NAME = ? and DBS.NAME = ? and PARTITIONS.PART_NAME in (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" Check whether it returns valid data