# Spark ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with timestamp columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive

I have hive table and want to operate with it using pyspark. One of my column have `timestamp` datatype. I can select it from hive, but I get an error when working through pyspark.

In pyspark I try execute this:

```
2020-09-08 13:21:29,142 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 249, 172.29.14.241, executor 7): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

2020-09-08 13:21:29,265 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 15.0 (TID 250, 172.29.14.238, executor 0): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1024
        at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$TreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:292)
        at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StringDictionaryTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:1820)
        at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StringTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:1517)
        at org.apache.orc.impl.ConvertTreeReaderFactory$TimestampFromStringGroupTreeReader.nextVector(ConvertTreeReaderFactory.java:1699)
        at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StructTreeReader.nextBatch(TreeReaderFactory.java:2059)
        at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.nextBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:1322)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcColumnarBatchReader.nextBatch(OrcColumnarBatchReader.java:196)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcColumnarBatchReader.nextKeyValue(OrcColumnarBatchReader.java:99)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceScanExec.scala:490)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.columnartorow_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:872)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:872)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:444)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:447)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2020-09-08 13:21:29,494 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 15.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 440, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 131, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o357.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 15.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 15.0 (TID 252, 172.29.14.238, executor 0): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1024
        at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$TreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:292)
        at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StringDictionaryTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:1820)
        at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StringTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:1517)
        at org.apache.orc.impl.ConvertTreeReaderFactory$TimestampFromStringGroupTreeReader.nextVector(ConvertTreeReaderFactory.java:1699)
        at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StructTreeReader.nextBatch(TreeReaderFactory.java:2059)
        at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.nextBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:1322)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcColumnarBatchReader.nextBatch(OrcColumnarBatchReader.java:196)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcColumnarBatchReader.nextKeyValue(OrcColumnarBatchReader.java:99)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceScanExec.scala:490)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.columnartorow_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:872)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:872)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:444)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:447)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2023)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:1972)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1971)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1971)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:950)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:950)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:950)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2203)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2152)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2141)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:752)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2093)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2114)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2133)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:467)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:420)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3625)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2695)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3616)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:763)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3614)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2695)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2902)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:300)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:337)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1024
        at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$TreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:292)
        at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StringDictionaryTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:1820)
        at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StringTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:1517)
        at org.apache.orc.impl.ConvertTreeReaderFactory$TimestampFromStringGroupTreeReader.nextVector(ConvertTreeReaderFactory.java:1699)
        at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StructTreeReader.nextBatch(TreeReaderFactory.java:2059)
        at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.nextBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:1322)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcColumnarBatchReader.nextBatch(OrcColumnarBatchReader.java:196)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcColumnarBatchReader.nextKeyValue(OrcColumnarBatchReader.java:99)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceScanExec.scala:490)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.columnartorow_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:872)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:872)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:444)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:447)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
```

In hte hive cli all is correct:

```
hive> select id, host, time_ from payments.transacts limit 20;
OK
15468499243     h1      2019-11-01 14:35:31
15468498828     h1      2019-11-01 14:35:31
15468498912     h2      2019-11-01 14:35:31
15468498995     h2      2019-11-01 14:35:31
15468499077     h1      2019-11-01 14:35:31
15468499162     h1      2019-11-01 14:35:31
15468499163     h1      2019-11-01 14:35:31
15468499245     h1      2019-11-01 14:35:31
15468498833     h2      2019-11-01 14:35:31
15468498834     h2      2019-11-01 14:35:31
15468498916     h2      2019-11-01 14:35:31
15468499002     h2      2019-11-01 14:35:31
15468499003     h2      2019-11-01 14:35:31
15468499084     h1      2019-11-01 14:35:31
15468499169     h1      2019-11-01 14:35:31
15468499252     h2      2019-11-01 14:35:31
15468498838     h1      2019-11-01 14:35:31
15468498921     h2      2019-11-01 14:35:31
15468499007     h1      2019-11-01 14:35:31
15468499008     h1      2019-11-01 14:35:31
```

If I try to get it without `time_` column, all is ok!

```
+-----------+----+                                                              
|         id|host|
+-----------+----+
|15468499243|  h1|
|15468498828|  h1|
|15468498912|  h2|
|15468498995|  h2|
|15468499077|  h1|
|15468499162|  h1|
|15468499163|  h1|
|15468499245|  h1|
|15468498833|  h2|
|15468498834|  h2|
|15468498916|  h2|
|15468499002|  h2|
|15468499003|  h2|
|15468499084|  h1|
|15468499169|  h1|
|15468499252|  h2|
|15468498838|  h1|
|15468498921|  h2|
|15468499007|  h1|
|15468499008|  h1|
+-----------+----+
```

What I shold change for correct working with timestamp from pyspark?

Comment: can you pls check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896587/hivei-got-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-while-i-query-the-hive-database

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer! I think It's not my situation. I see, that I have problems only with timestamp columns (other selecting correctly). My table is an existing table stored in the ORC format. Are the any suggestions?

Comment: @GrigorySkvortsov - Where you able to resolve this problem? I have similar problem  I am not able to read the data on HDFS which has timestamp columns.  Wanted to understand how did you overcome this?